# Convert a number (i. e. 5) to length of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer, web-component

I want to create a property on a polymer custom element that let's the user define a number of elements to repeat.

```
<my-element repeated-elements='5'></my-element>
```

This should tell my element to repeat the element inside of the component five times. For that I need an array with length of 5, so anything like this would do:

```
['','','','','']
```

Is there a way to do this in JavaScript? The number would be passed as a number, not a string. So somehow I would need to convert any number to the amount of array items in an array. Metaphorically speaking:

```
convertToArrayLength(5);
```

I'm completely lost here, I have no idea at all how this could be done.

Comment: How about `var a = new Array(5);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [array constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) does exactly that:

```
var arr = Array(5);

console.log(arr, arr.length);
//=> Array [ <5 empty slots> ] 5
```

You don't need to put `new` before calling `Array` (just a peculiarity of the API).

Note though that arrays in JavaScript are dynamic, so most of the time you don't need to specify the length of your array beforehand and can simply initialize your variable with:

```
var arr = [];
// And then push to it as you go:
arr.push(x);
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Just a few seconds after posting I realized this could have been done easily with a for-loop as well. Sometimes you lose all your problem-solving skills because you think too much in libraries like lodash lol...

Comment: Ah yea, this kind of library is pretty tough for a beginner. I was also afraid of mixing up libraries with the language itself when learning JS, so I actually only began touching jQuery one year after starting learning vanilla JavaScript, while some people *begin* learning jQuery before anything else, but then they have trouble understanding how the language actually works.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript will re size the array automatically as you push to it.

```
var array = new Array(5); // undefined
array.length; // 5
array.push("FOO"); // 6
array.length; // 6
```

All you have to do is make sure you assign the variable as an Array with either `[]` or `new Array`